# Reliable way to convert bazel target path into filesystem path?

Tags: bazel

Is there a reliable way for outside tools to reference files generated by Bazel? More specifically: how to I convert target paths into bazel-bin (or so) paths?

I can determine the `outs` of target:

`$ bazel query 'labels(outs, //bababot:bababot_server_kube_dev_deployment_json)'
//bababot:bababot_server_kube_dev_deployment.json`

The `//bababot:bababot_server_kube_dev_deployment.json` is *almost* what I need, except that I need the string `bazel-bin/bababot/bababot_server_kube_dev_deployment.json`, or equivalent.

How can I get that reliably? I imagine that I can start by replacing `//` for `bazel info bazel-bin` and replacing `:` for `/`. Is there a less brittle way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bazel has a [Build Event Protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html), check out the `NamedSetOfFiles` events