# Is there a Bazel command line to determine the absolute path of the outputs for one or more given labels?

Tags: bazel

I know there is `bazel info <...> bazel-bin` but that is only giving the output path prefix.  I am hoping for some fancy `cquery` or `aquery` to get the complete path for the outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no an easy way to get that (see related discussions below), but if your target is *runnable* you can use [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8739#issuecomment-511060484) nice trick:

```sh
bazel run --run_under "echo" //path/to/folder:target
```

This will print the full path of the binary on disk (within the bazel cache folder).

A more general way to get output paths for a target would be through `aquery`, e.g.

```sh
bazel aquery "//path/to/folder:target" --noinclude_commandline --output=text
```

This will print the outputs for all the actions related to the given target (for a `cc_binary` these will include the object files, the binary, the stripped binary, etc...) - you can then grep for `Outputs` and extract the path.

This is an example output for a `cc_binary`:

```sh
> bazel aquery "//path/to/folder:target" --noinclude_commandline --output=text

action 'Compiling path/to/folder/main.cc'
  Mnemonic: CppCompile
  Target: //path/to/folder:target
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: ...
  Inputs: [..., path/to/folder/main.cc]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/_objs/target/main.pic.d,
            bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/_objs/target/main.pic.o]

...

action 'Linking path/to/folder/target'
  Mnemonic: CppLink
  Target: //path/to/folder:target
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: ...
  Inputs: [..., bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/_objs/target/main.pic.o, ...]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/target]

action 'Stripping path/to/folder/target.stripped for //path/to/folder:target'
  Mnemonic: CcStrip
  Target: //path/to/folder:target
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: ...
  Inputs: [..., bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/target]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/target.stripped]

...
...
...
```

Paths are relative, but you can resolve them by getting the *workspace* folder with `bazel info workspace`.

If you're interested in the output(s) of a specific action, for example the final binary resulting from linking, you can filter by *mnemonic* type:

```sh
> bazel aquery "mnemonic(CppLink, //path/to/folder:target)" --noinclude_commandline --output=text

action 'Linking path/to/folder/target'
  Mnemonic: CppLink
  Target: //path/to/folder:target
  Configuration: k8-fastbuild
  ActionKey: ...
  Inputs: [..., bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/_objs/target/target.pic.o, ...]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/path/to/folder/target]
```

Not a full answer, but hope this helps.

Other related discussions:

- [Bazel: How do you get the path to a generated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859615/bazel-how-do-you-get-the-path-to-a-generated-file)
- [Reliable way to convert bazel target path into filesystem path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505348/reliable-way-to-convert-bazel-target-path-into-filesystem-path)
- [Bazel: how to get path to output binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292429/bazel-how-to-get-path-to-output-binary)